# how can I use python3 to output data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint 
r = requests.get('http://www.geologycloud.tw/data/zh-tw/liquefaction?area=%E5%98%89%E7%BE%A9&classify=%E9%AB%98%E6%BD%9B%E5%8B%A2&all=true')
doc = json.loads(r.text)
pprint(doc['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'])
```

Comment: What's your question exactly ???

Comment: What is it that you're asking? The given code outputs [something](https://i.gyazo.com/a4b5aac60f322ec91892678f6d04cb18.png) for me.

Comment: the code runs, I think they are just looking to save it to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to save data to disk.  I would try this:

```
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint 
import pickle

r = requests.get('http://www.geologycloud.tw/data/zh-tw/liquefaction?area=%E5%98%89%E7%BE%A9&classify=%E9%AB%98%E6%BD%9B%E5%8B%A2&all=true')
doc = json.loads(r.text)
pprint(doc['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'])

with open('data.pkl', 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(doc['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'], output)
```